# The usage of variables in strtotime() function as well as in html structures

Tags: php

Sorry for asking this question, but I am very new in php and I am stucked at this issue. I use the code part to read a txt file as below:

I want to read a txt file in php and create an event by using the information coming from the text.

events.txt includes:

```
SEPTEMBER-21-2015-10am
Google Event
http://www.google.com
That is very enjoyable

...

$fh = fopen('events.txt','r');
$counter = 0;
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    if($counter % 4 == 0)
    {
        $eventDate = explode("-",$line);
    }
    if($counter % 4 == 1)
    {
        $eventTitle = $line;
    }
    if($counter % 4 == 2)
    {
        $eventLink = $line;
    }
    if($counter % 4 == 3)
    {
        $eventDesc = $line;
    }
    ++$counter;
}
fclose($fh);
```

I am able to read my file and assign my data to the related variables. However, I would like to use them to create $event1 like:

```
$event1 = $calendar->event()->condition('timestamp', strtotime($eventDate[0],$arrayDate[1],$arrayDate[2]))->title($eventTitle)->output('<a href=$eventLink target="newWin">[$eventDate[3]+': '+$eventTitle</a><br />$eventDesc');
```

I couldnt find out the syntax to run something like above. In the original example.php file, it is:

```
$event1 = $calendar->event()->condition('timestamp', strtotime(date('F').' 21, '.date('Y')))->title('Hello All')->output('<a href="http://google.com">Going to Google</a><br />Description is here.');
```

I appreciate if someone helps me to learn this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want evalute runtime the $eventLink and $eventDat[..] variable you must enclose your `<a ...>` within `"` (double quote) and not `'`  (single quote)

this way :

```
 "<a href=$eventLink target='newWin'>[$eventDate[3]+": "+$eventTitle</a><br />$eventDesc"
```

because in PHP  the value in single quote are display `as is` while the value in double quote is evaluate runtime